# Web Access Control Service - what is it for?

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, windows-services

What is the **Web Access Control Service** (`wacsvc.exe`) for?

Can I safely disable it?

Because every once in a while, it goes crazy, and uses 99% CPU until it is restarted.

This is on a Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!! I finally figured it out. It is a component of the Internet filter we have installed ([CleanInter.net](http://www.cleaninter.net)). I won't disable it, I guess. But it sure would be nice if it did not hog the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

from google I found out, this services is `Access Connections Main Service` and belongs to the `ThinkPad Access Connections suite`. So lok at the Lenovo site for an update and lok into the documentation what this tool does.

Comment: Oh ThinkDisadvantage, how I loathe thee.

Comment: I don't think so... This computer is an HP and does not have ThinkPad Access Connections suite installed. This service is a Windows service, but what is it for?

Comment: this is not a Windows service. I don't have it ;) Run ProcessExplorer, look at the commandline of the tool, go to the folder and look at the file properties (Product and Company name).

Comment: @magicandre1981 It definitely is not part of ThinkPad Access Connections suite. See my post.